# eclipse EE Juno VS Glassfish error: glassfish\domains\domain1 does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish-3

I am using eclipse ee juno. I'm currently trying to set-Up Glassfish in eclipse via the the New Server wizard. Now, after hitting the NEXT button in the dialog box (see first screenshot) eclipse raises this error glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1 does not exist (see second screenshot).

[image: First error]

[image]

Comment: Maybe it doesn't exist in this path. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and while I didn't solve it, unfortunately, I did find a work around: I created a new domain by running:

```
$ asadmin create-domain --adminport 4848 --adminuser admin mydomain
```

Run the command from the `glassfish\glassfish\bin` folder.

Comment: Excuse me but did you ran this command in your dos box or is there some specific command tool for this ?

Comment: How do you run a command from the glassfish\glassfish\bin folder ?

Comment: From the command prompt, yes. Alternatively, you can double-click `asadamin.bat` in the `glassfish\glassfish\bin` folder to start the admin console. If you do this, you can drop the 'asadmin' from the start of the command.

Comment: In that case, while in `glassfish\glassfish\bin`, hold `shift` and right click, then choose 'open command window here'. Then type the command. If you have any more trouble, I suggest you consult a tutorial on the web.

Comment: Doesnt work neither. I'll try one of the few tutorials on the web. Thank again for your time

Answer (score 0):

there is an easiest way to solve this problem.
when downloading glassFish, download the zip and everything after that is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Although late reply, but may be useful to someone facing similar issues.

If no domain exist your glassfish path i.e say C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\ then you can create a new domain in the same path as follows:

1. Navigate to  C:\glassfish4\bin\ directory and double click on asadmin.bat. It will open a command prompt as 
   asadmin >
2. Type the following command
   asadmin > create-domain --adminport 4848 domain1
3. Click enter repeatedly to keep the default settings viz. username (admin)  password  and other things.
4. Thats it. You will find the domain1 created under C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\  directory with all default configurations.

If want to create domain in another directory or want some more info then can refer Oracle Glassfish Reference Manual :

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1758/create-domain-1/index.html